# Jquery Ajax Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

```
var ownDataTable = $(".own_cases_table").dataTable();

$.ajax({
        url : "api/v1/cases/"+encodeURIComponent(uid)+"/active",
        type : "get",
        headers : { "Authorization" : api_key },
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(response) {
            if (response.error) {

            } else {
                var cases = response.cases;
                ownDataTable.fnClearTable();
                for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
                    console.log(cases[i].case_name);
                    ownDataTable.fnAddData([ cases[i].case_name, cases[i].slide_img, 'Daha Fazla', 'action' ]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML :

```
<!-- TABLE FOR MOBILE START -->
              <table class="table mb30 own_cases_table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><?php echo _("Olgu"); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo _("Dijital Slide"); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo _("Daha Fazla"); ?></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </div>
             <!-- TABLE FOR MOBILE END -->

          <div class="table-responsive hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          <table class="table own_cases_table">
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th><?php echo _("Olgu"); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo _("Dijital Slide"); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo _("Daha Fazla"); ?></th>
                    <th></th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>                 
              </tbody>
           </table>
```

i am using datatables but no data is added in datatables. Always writes "No data avaliable in table" 
i checked cases has data and i `$(".own_cases_table").DataTable();` but nothing changed.

How i can add data into my tables ?

I tried with ownDataTable.row.add() but same result occured

Comment: Do share a fiddle of the same..

Comment: You could use response as a static object!

Comment: Shoudnt this be `var cases = response.data;`

Comment: when i tried with one table, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to initalize datatable.

$('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );

from https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html